# Implementation of MergeSort algorithm using OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, mergesort

I am trying to implement Mergesort algorithm using OpenMP for first time. I came across this block of code where they are using parallel sections directive to divide the unsorted array. But for Repeatedly merging the subarrays to produce new sorted array there is no parallel implementation. I have added the parallel directive for each loop in the merge method.Will this create the overhead on thread? I am not sure if this is right.Please correct me if I am wrong.How to proceed.Thanks.

```
void merge_divide(int array[],int low,int high)
{
int mid;
if(low<high)
{
 mid=(low+high)/2;
 #pragma omp parallel sections
{
#pragma omp section
{
merge_divide(array,low,mid);
}   
#pragma omp section
{
merge_divide(array,mid+1,high);
}
}
merge_conquer(array,low,mid,high);
}

    Merge method 
    void merge_conquer(int array[],int low,int mid,int high)
{
  int temp[30];
  int i,j,k,m;
  j=low;
  m=mid+1;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(i=low; j<=mid && m<=high ; i++)
  {
     if(array[j]<=array[m])
     {
         temp[i]=array[j];
         j++;
     }
     else
     {
         temp[i]=array[m];
         m++;
     }
  }
  if(j>mid)
  {
    #pragma omp parallel for
     for(k=m; k<=high; k++)
     {
         temp[i]=array[k];
         i++;
     }
  }
  else
  {
    #pragma omp parallel for
     for(k=j; k<=mid; k++)
     {
        temp[i]=array[k];
        i++;
     }
  }
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(k=low; k<=high; k++)
     array[k]=temp[k];
}
```

Comment: Your code is full of data races. I suggest you to get familiar with the basics of openmp and try again. [This hands on tutorial](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf) helped me a lot to get started.

Comment: @ Paul R. Can you please explain a little bit more like which part of code is of data races? so that i can take a look into it and correct it . Thanks a lot

Comment: You modify non-thread local variables (like i,j,k,...) from multiple threads without synchronization. Your code will most likely crash or produce non-sense. You need to familiarize yourself with the basics of multi-threading. Your code shows hat you need to learn more than what fits into SO comments or even a SO answer. The link I've posted in my first comment would be a good start.

Comment: @PaulR. A little clarification: `i` and `k` are implicitly private (i.e. thread-local) within their respective loops due to the fact that they are loop variables. The value of `i` outside of the loop is another story... so are the race conditions around `j` and `m`.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks for clarifying. I admit that I didn't know this. I always used openmp with c++, where I declared the for loop variables in the loop header. But as you said, this still leaves us with several race conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understood it better now. I will either use sections and set the number of threads or use task directive for the merge_divide method. I will clean up the junk code. I will only paralleize merge_divide method. I came across this link which might be useful.             https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/296272